# How do I find the length of a column ending at a specific value within the column?

Tags: r

How do I find the length of a column ending at a specific value within the column in R?

I have been stuck on this for hours please help!

Comment: Please post some data/code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is incomplete: for example, do you want the first instance of the specific value?  if so, then

`which( my_matrix[,my_column_number] == my_value)`   will return the index of the match, which happens to be the length to that point in the column. (Usual warnings about using `==` with floating-point data apply).